# glsl cast bool to float

Tags: glsl

I want to set a `float` value to `1.0` if one vector equals another, and `0.0` if the vectors are not equal

```
if( v1 == v2 )  floatVal = 1.0 ;
else  floatVal = 0.0 ;
```

But wouldn't it be "faster" or an optimization just to set

```
floatVal = (v1 == v2) ;
```

But it doesn't work.  You can't implicitly (or explicitly) convert float to bool?  Is there a way to do this or do I have to use the `if` statement branch?

Answer (score 17):

Didn't you try "float(bool)" function?

GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf section 5.4.1 says you can do all those conversions.

Comment: This remains valid in GLSL 4.3, same section, and behaves as follows: "When a constructor is used to convert a bool to any
integer or floating-point type, false is converted to 0 or 0.0, and true is converted to 1 or 1.0."

Answer (score 7):

CuriousChettai's right. Just write:

```
floatVal = float(v1 == v2);
```

GLSL gives you a compile-error if you assign values with possible loss of precision. So you can do things like:

```
float f = 3;       // works
int i = 3.0;       // compiler-error
int j = int(3.0);  // works
```